# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una condición IF en AJAX?

Tags: ajax

¿Cómo puedo hacer una condición IF? Estoy comparando el ID de combo con un campo de base de datos en Ajax. Aquí está mi código:

```
      $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/comprarbloqueo/ComBloLlenar_Datos?ComBloid=' + IdComBloCli,
            type: 'POST',                    
            data: "",
            contentType: 'json; charset=utf-8',                
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).each(function (i, row) {
                    // (vTxtNacionalidad = row.CLI_Nacionalidad) {
                    vCboNacionalidad = row.CLI_Nacionalidad;
                    vTxtPasaporte = row.Pasaporte;
                    vTxtNombre = row.CLI_Nombre;
                    vTxtApellidoPa = row.CLI_ApellidoPa;
                    vTxtApellidoMa = row.CLI_ApellidoMa;
                    vTxtTelefono = row.CLI_Telefono;
                })

                if ($("#cboNacionalidad") = val(vCboNacionalidad)) {
                    $("#txtPasaporte").val(vTxtPasaporte);
                    $("#txtNombre").val(vTxtNombre);
                    $("#txtApellidoPa").val(vTxtApellidoPa);
                    $("#txtApellidoMa").val(vTxtApellidoMa);
                    $("#txtTelefono").val(vTxtTelefono);
                } else {
                    alert("Eres cliente nuevo");
                }
                    //alert("Datos traidos correctamente");                  

             },
```

Con la condición IF quiero hacer el control; por ejemplo, al seleccionar el combo, si existe un campo nacionalidad en SQL quiero que me muestre todos los campos que está debajo de Nacionalidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo exactamente lo que tratas hacer, deberías explicar un codigo lo que intentas hacer, pero de antemano ese if está mal, para hace la comparación se usa el doble "=" ==

Comment: ¿Por qué usas POST, si no estás mandando nada? Usa GET que es lo que estás haciendo con el Query Param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu función obtiene bien los datos: lo único que tienes que hacer es obtener el valor de campo que quieres comparar $('#idCampoABuscar').val(), eso obtiene un dato a comparar, entoces solo queda hacer == con el otro valor

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: '/comprarbloqueo/ComBloLlenar_Datos?ComBloid=' + IdComBloCli,
            type: 'POST',                    
            data: "",
            contentType: 'json; charset=utf-8',                
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).each(function (i, row) {
                    // (vTxtNacionalidad = row.CLI_Nacionalidad) {
                    vCboNacionalidad = row.CLI_Nacionalidad;
                    vTxtPasaporte = row.Pasaporte;
                    vTxtNombre = row.CLI_Nombre;
                    vTxtApellidoPa = row.CLI_ApellidoPa;
                    vTxtApellidoMa = row.CLI_ApellidoMa;
                    vTxtTelefono = row.CLI_Telefono;
                })

                if ($("#cboNacionalidad").val() == vCboNacionalidad) {
                    $("#txtPasaporte").val(vTxtPasaporte);
                    $("#txtNombre").val(vTxtNombre);
                    $("#txtApellidoPa").val(vTxtApellidoPa);
                    $("#txtApellidoMa").val(vTxtApellidoMa);
                    $("#txtTelefono").val(vTxtTelefono);
                } else {
                    alert("Eres Cliente Nuevo");
                }
                    //alert("Datos traidos correctamente");                  

             },
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis Fernando